# Why when I use variables on SQL the Database Engine avoid the indexes?

Tags: sql, indexing, ssis

I'm improving our SSIS process passing the variables through a "declare" and I found this:

Unusing declare (Execution time: 1 second)

```
select *
from fact_Venta
where Data_ID >= 20201001
and Data_ID <= 20201001
```

[image: Execution Plan]

Using declare (Execution time: 2 minutes)

```
declare @data1 as int = 20201001
declare @data2 as int = 20201001
select *
from fact_Venta
where Data_ID >= @data1
and Data_ID <= @data2
```

[image: Execution Plan]

As you can see, when I use the "declare" SQL Database Engine don't use the Index

For more information, that's the Index used for the column on the "where"
[image: Index]

Can someone explain me why this happen?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Same server on both? Same SET options on both? The query plans are only showing a fragment of what's available. You can paste the full plans into https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and then link them into your question.

Comment: Hi @billinkc . Both querys were on the same server and with the same SET options. There you have the full both executions to show that there are executed both on the same server, same set options and the same time (but on the brentozar web are not represented correctly the querys with the declares): https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJg6_7NDP

Comment: Here you have using Variables https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkSxs7VPv

Comment: And here without variables https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ8soXEww

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278035/why-when-i-use-variables-on-sql-the-database-engine-avoid-the-indexes

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/why-when-i-use-variables-on-sql-the-database-engine-avoid-the-indexes#post-3797080

Comment: There are more information and solutions to this case

Answer (score 0):

Parameter sniffing is the problem

Just use option(recompile) at the end

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/278035/why-when-i-use-variables-on-sql-the-database-engine-avoid-the-indexes
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/why-when-i-use-variables-on-sql-the-database-engine-avoid-the-indexes#post-3797080

More information there